# Missing basic commands. Stuck without being able to install anything

Tags: shell, ssh, apt, sudo, root

I am accessing the machine through SSH, I am root.

Tried getting the Linux version with
`hostnamectl`
Got
`-sh: hostnamectl: command not found`

Same for `lsb_release`, `sudo`, `apt-get`, `yum`, `dpkg`, etc.

I got as far as downloading the apt package with
`wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_2.3.6_amd64.deb -O apt.deb`
but I can't unpack it since `dpkg` isn't installed.

Also there's no "os-release" file inside /etc/

By running `uname` I get "Linux", and by running `cat /etc/*version` the output is `2.06.03.cdv`.

Is there any way I could get unstuck and start installing packages normally?

Comment: Running `uname -srm` returns `Linux 3.10.107 x86_64`

Comment: Did you login as root? What does `echo $PATH` show?

Comment: What is the full output of `uname -a`? Is there a /var/cache directory, and if so can you add the output of `ls -l /var/cache` to the question - it may give some clues about which package manager is being used?

Comment: You mean you are trying to find out what distro runs on this machine? Perhaps `ls /etc/*release /etc/*version` helps. Also, under /var/lib, check if it has subdirectories like `apt`, `dnf`, `yum`, `rpm` and so on. That should give a clue as well. A glance at /boot might help, too; does it use Grub? Does the Grub or other bootloader's config file contain anything that identifies the distro?

Comment: `echo $PATH` 
returns `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/sbin:/opt/bin:/opt/usr/bin:/opt/usr/sbin:/opt/python/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`,
`uname -a` returns 
`Linux N5550 3.10.107 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jul 20 14:32:51 CST 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
`ls -l /var/cache/ ` returns three folders and two files:
cups/ fontconfig/ ldconfig/ mac mac2

Comment: It'd also be interesting to know how you ended up in this situation

Comment: A google search for N5550 turns up a NAS box. The 2018/7/20 date for the kernel seems rather late for this model. If it is a NAS box it is totally possible that you don't have a package manager, and you install software just using `cp`.

Comment: By reading the support page of the [Thecus N5550 NAS box](http://www.thecus.com/product.php?PROD_ID=76), it looks like the the OS of the NAS box is treated as a single core "firmware" image, plus a number of optional installable "modules". It seems that installation and management of these is intended to be done through the web GUI, so command-line package management tools like `apt`, `dpkg`, `dnf`, `yum`, `rpm` might not be applicable to this "special-purpose hardware-specific NAS distribution" at all. This is pretty normal for embedded/appliance solutions.

Comment: Got as far as manually copying the 'apt' binaries to /usr/bin, but when I tried executing it I get an error saying that I am missing a library. When trying to copy the library file to /usr/lib64 on the remote machine, found out the volume it's mounted on is 'read-only'. Wasn't able to resize/change permissions on that partition. It seems I hit a (permanent?) roadblock. Looking forward for more suggestions/tips.